# Linux - default OpenGL version

Tags: linux, ubuntu, opengl, glx

I work on Ubuntu 18.04. I don't define `GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES`. I load "core" OpenGL functions using `glXGetProcAddress`. My application links to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so`. Some legacy OpenGL functions are available without defining `GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES` or calling `glXGetProcAddress`, for example `glColor3f`. Which OpenGL version (functions) is available by default under Linux ?

**Edit**

I assume that the hardware supports the newest OpenGL version. Moreover I use compatibility profile and OpenGL headers (`gl.h, glext.h`) from the standard Ubuntu location: `/usr/include/GL`. It looks like that those headers have been installed by `mesa-common-dev` apt package.

Comment: Whichever you request (as long as your GPU driver supports it).

Comment: @BDL I assume that the hardware supports the newest OpenGL version. Creating a OpenGL context, for example 4.6 doesn't provide automatically appropriate functions pointers. I have asked which OpenGL functions are availalbe without defining GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES using glxGetProcAddress (or any other thirdy party loader).

Comment: So you are just interested which function definitions are available? I ask this because when you, for example, request a 4.6 core context, `glColor3f` will be available, but calling it will give you an error since it's deprecated in a core profile. Please also add where you got the `gl.h` headerfile from (mesa probably? or maybe libgl or glproto?).

Comment: You're right, I should provide more information. Yes, I'm interested which function definitions are available by default. I use compatibility profile and OpenGL headers (`gl.h, glext.h`) from the standard Ubuntu location: `/usr/include/GL`. It looks like that those headers have been installed by `mesa-common-dev` apt package. My application explicitly links only to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so` but ldd shows that it is also linked to nvidia proprietary drivers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traditionally, the `libGL.so` on Linux is provided by the vendor of your graphics driver. There is no real "default" version. The closes thing to a standard you can find in that regard is the [OpenGL® Application Binary Interface for Linux](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/ABI) which states:

> 3.4. The libraries must export all OpenGL 1.2, GLU 1.3, GLX 1.3, and ARB_multitexture entry points statically.

and

> 4.5. All OpenGL 1.2 and ARB_multitexture, GLU 1.3, and GLX 1.3 entry points and enumerants must be present in the corresponding header files gl.h, glu.h, and glx.h, even if only OpenGL 1.1 is implemented at runtime by the associated runtime libraries.

So that is basically the set of directly exported GL functions you can rely on. Typically, the GL libs of various vendors export much more, but the official way yo query things is the extension mechanism.

Note that on Linux, the modern way to use OpenGL is by the [vendor-neutral GL dispatch library](https://github.com/NVIDIA/libglvnd) which provides `libOpenGL.so` instead of `libGL.so`. It seems to export all core OpenGL functions known at the time it was built. But that doesn't mean that the particular vendor implementation will support all these functions.